# set programmatically an option that is not the default one

Tags: magento-1.9, select

I have a select, and programmatically sets the default value:

```
$attributes->setData($attributeToApply->getAttributeCode(), $attributeToApply->getDefaultValue());
```

select 'foo' has option 'bar' with order '0' and option 'baz' with order '1'. 'bar' is the default option.

But now I need to apply another value that is not the default one, for one concrete attribute code.

```
if ($attributes->getData($attributeToApply->getAttributeCode()!='foo') {
    $attributes->setData($attributeToApply->getAttributeCode(), $attributeToApply->getDefaultValue());
} else {
    $attributes->setData($attributeToApply->getAttributeCode(), $attributeToApply->/* what should I use here?? */);
}
```

Default value has order: 0, and the other value has order: 1. How can I set it by it's order? or at least by its option label?

Edit: I'm trying this statement, but it's still setting default value:

```
$attributes->setData($attributeToApply->getAttributeCode(), 'baz');
```

Comment: Do you try to add options "bar","baz" to the attribute "foo"?

Comment: They are added, and they work correctly. The only thing is that just now I don't know what exactly I should write to select programmatically 'baz' instead of default 'bar'